# Listar todos synonyms no Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Como faço para listar todos os synonyms(sinônimos) presentes em meu banco de dados? Preciso saber quais que estão criados para comparar entre bancos o que existe. Tentei com o código abaixo mas não retorna sinônimos:

```
select * from all_objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from all_synonyms;
```

Existe uma view para cada tipo de objecto que tu crias.
exemplo: all_tables, all_views, all_procedures......

Comment: pow vacilei, resolveu. kkkk consegui trazer os synonyms. valeu Renato.

Comment: Quando não souber que tabela do metadados usar ... select * from DICT

Comment: Eu prefiro usar a `user_synonyns`, por trazer somente os que estão válidos, do usuário conectado.